# file upload and live worker in GoogleAppsEngine with Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm pretty new to pythonDev and GAE, just run through "getting started" from google site, so any dumb tips will be appreciated.

I want to do the following:

1. Upload files to BlobStore
2. A 'worker' to process blob files. By 'worker' I mean a listener that get newly added files, which can be really huge text files.
3. Save a process log and delete the file from BlobStore
4. Then, save processed data to bigTable

I'm using the boilerplate available in this [video](https://sites.google.com/site/io/rapid-development-with-python-django-and-google-app-engine) (and can be downloaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/downloads/detail?name=appengine_helper_for_django-r117.zip&can=2&q=))

Any questions or further explanation, just ask. 
Thanks :)

Comment: see this tutorial https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview

Comment: the problem is with the boilerplate i'm using... It's use a _WSGIHandler_ instead of _WSGIApplication_, so i can't create the class _UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler)_ (or, at least, i don't know how)

Answer (score 0):

App engine is a listener by default. If you have received the blob you can start a task to process the blob. You van find examples in the GAE documentation.